# gtk_container_get_children

Tags: c

[image]When list of stations is printed in Preset rol list and you are at the begining or at the end of the list, you see many empty items.
I create list of about 20 stations and try to display them, go to the begining and to the end of the list.
I think the problem is in this piece of code:

```
static void add_button_clicked_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    preset *ps;
    gchar *buffer;
    GtkTreeIter iter = {0};
    GtkAdjustment* v_scb;
    GtkTreePath *path = NULL;
    GList* menuitems;
    GtkWidget *menuitem;

    ps = malloc(sizeof(preset));
    ps->title = g_strdup(_("unnamed"));
    ps->freq = rint(gtk_adjustment_get_value(adj)) / STEPS;
    settings.presets = g_list_append(settings.presets, (gpointer) ps);
    buffer = g_strdup_printf("%.2f", ps->freq);

    gtk_list_store_append(list_store, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(list_store, &iter, 0, ps->title, 1, buffer, -1);

    g_free(buffer);
    gtk_tree_selection_unselect_all(selection);

    v_scb = gtk_scrollable_get_vadjustment(GTK_SCROLLABLE(list_view));
    gtk_adjustment_set_value(v_scb, gtk_adjustment_get_upper(v_scb));

    if (main_visible) {
        gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(preset_combo), ps->title);
        mom_ps = g_list_length(settings.presets) - 1;
        preset_combo_set_item(mom_ps);

        menuitems = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(tray_menu));
        menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label(ps->title); 

        gtk_menu_shell_insert(GTK_MENU_SHELL(tray_menu), menuitem, mom_ps);     
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menuitem), "activate", (GCallback)preset_menuitem_activate_cb, (gpointer)mom_ps);
        gtk_widget_show(menuitem);
    }

    buffer = g_strdup_printf("%d", g_list_length(settings.presets) - 1);
    path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string(buffer);
    g_free(buffer);
    gtk_tree_view_set_cursor(GTK_TREE_VIEW(list_view), path, NULL, FALSE);
    gtk_tree_path_free(path);
}
```

Could you please suggest me how can correct it?

Comment: Really hard for me to tell your proficiency due to your question asked compared to the code shown... but if you're just calling the line that sets menuitems so the function runs, throw `void` in front of the function call so it just discards any return value instead of assigning it to a variable and then wasting memory.

Answer (score 5):

Inside of the `if (main_visible)`, you have:

`menuitems = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(tray_menu));`

That is, you're setting the value of `menuitems` to the return value of that function call.  However, none of the rest of your code actually does anything with menuitems.  So, the compiler gives you that warning.

Fixing it might be as easy as simply getting rid of menuitems:

`gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(tray_menu));`

That would definitely get rid of the warning.  But you have to think about it: Maybe you *should* be doing something with the return value of that function call, and the reason that you're not doing anything with it is that you forgot to (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

warning: variable 'menuitems' set but not used

Your compiler in layman's terms is saying the following:

Dude... youve created a class with a few attributes, one of which are called 'menuitems'. That's all well mate, but when you actually create an instance and assign all the variables, youve set 'menuitems' but youre never using that variable to do anything with it. its just sitting there doing nothing at all. So mate it's no problem at all as I can still run your program but im just warning you that the 'menuitems' variable is doing **** all as you're never using the variable itself. Just warning you bro :D  other than that have a good day

So its just a warning to let you know you have a variable no being used for any specific reason other than storing a value in there but never accessing it to do something useful. So either comment it out since youre not actually doing anything with it.. or use it, or just enjoy reading the warning but it wont affect the way your program runs.

The warnings get displayed mainly to get the developer more aware of their own code and whats happening.